# Playing a sound file in a cordova plugin in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cordova

I have created a cordova plugin which has some wav files. These are in Plugins folder. I'm trying to play a sound but I don't where is the location of the file I'm looking for within the project. The code I'm using is the following:

```
NSString * sourcePath = @"Where?";

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:soundFilePath]){

    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

    NSError *error = nil;
    AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:&error];


    player.numberOfLoops = -1; //Infinite

    [player play];

}
```

I have tried different locations such as:

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/mywavfile.wav",[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]] 

NSString *soundFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Plugins/cordova.plugin/mywavfile.wav",[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]

NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mywavfile"  ofType:@"wav"];
```

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to expose the folder in www foder. In config.xml I used the cordova plugin command

```
<asset src="www/sounds/myfile.m4a" target="sounds/myfile.m4a"/>
```

And the file exists in www/sounds/myfile.m4a folder.